# Why TestNG Assertion is not getting called?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

```
import org.testng.asserts.Assertion;

public class A extends B{
     Assertion ASSERTOR = new Assertion();
     ASSERTOR.assertEquals("abc", "dfff");
     System.out.println("Do not print this");
}
```

In the above code, I expected it to fail at Assertion, but it prints the statement.
The same is done at my coworkers computer, but his code works fine. His TestNG version is same as mine. We work on the same repository. When I push the code in GIT, the ASSERTOR works as expected.  It does not work on my local machine only.

If I type `org.testng.Assert.assertEquals` (on my local machine), then this works fine.

What else could have gone wrong here?
Why does this happen?

Comment: Your sample is not compiling. BTW, the logic seems ok. And as it is working on another computer, then the issue is in your computer, not in the code.

Comment: Code snippet looks fine. Check the configuration in your local machine, clean the project and re-build it then try re-running the same.